# Retrieve List of Foursquare Venue Categories without Authenticating

Tags: foursquare

A list of venues is available through the API (using the `https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search` endpoint), but I cannot do the same for a list of categories. Is there a way I can get the list of categories without authenticating?

I think it makes sense in the same way a list of venues makes sense w/o the need to authenticate, but this is just my opinion.

Comment: Agreed. It should be easier to grab the venue categories. Here's a Gist containing the venue category object - https://gist.github.com/brettdewoody/a2303d955f4e28b6ca8632fa48f82168

Comment: thanks for creating this repo Brett, I'll definitely use it for now. do you know if these categories change very often at all?

Comment: I don't believe they change frequently. New categories _may_ be added, I imagine, but it seems the existing categories are very stable. Meaning their `id`, `name`, etc stay the same.

Comment: Also, you can check for updates to this using the Foursquare API Explorer - https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/categories.

Comment: Great, it should make sense to have these stored locally in a json then, thanks a lot Brett

Comment: Turns out the https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/categories endpoint doesn't require user authentication so you should be able to query it once your app is setup.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help! I appreciate

Comment: There's now a page listing all the categories in the docs - https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/resources/categories